# Message Type safety in Spring Integration DSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

If I define a Jms Integration flow in this way is there a way to avoid the casting of the Message type in the handler? Or perhaps I should be implementation the JMS Integration in a different way?

```
@EnableJms
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
public class JmsInboundFlow {
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsInboundFlow.class);

@Autowired
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory;

@Autowired
private JmsMessageMyPojoHandlerService handlerService;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(messageDrivenChannelAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory).destination("queuName")
            .errorChannel(jmsMyPojoErrorChannel()))
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(MyPojo.class))
            .handle(message -> handlerService.addEvent((Message<MyPojo>) message))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel jmsMyPojoErrorChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct("customErrorChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow customErrorFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(jmsMyPojoErrorChannel())
            .handle(msg -> logger.error("Error processing JMS message " + msg.getPayload()))
            .get();
}
}
```

Comment: it seems the fluent builder is not type safe, but I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.handle(service, method)` variant - and Framework will take care about proper casting for you.

Comment: is this still the way to go?

Comment: Please, raise a new SO question with much more detail and we will try to work out the plan for your concern.